# Removing PowerShell 1.0 from Windows 7

Tags: powershell

How can I remove PowerShell 1.0 from Windows 7 to install PowerShell 2.0.? I can't find it in the list of installed programs and updates.

Answer (score 10):

Powershell 2.0 is installed on Windows7 by default.  It's not possible to install 1.0 on Win7.  It's misleading a bit because some places still reference 1.0 in the directory structure and registry but if you're on Win7, it's PowerShell 2.0

Comment: It's misleading *a lot*. I am a big PowerShell fan but in my opinion this versioning decision was one of the worst the team made.

Answer (score 4):

To see the version of PowerShell you have, type in:

```
$PSVersionTable
```

at the PSH (console window or ISE). This will result in something like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4927
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell is a required component of the Windows 7 OS.  All of the troubleshooting features (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting) rely upon PowerShell to execute the underlying troubleshooting logic.